# When to compress HTTP POST data?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, optimization, compression

I am writing a client that frequently sends small portions of data via HTTPS. The data can be anything from 50 UTF-8 chars to 10k chars - mostly human readable log data. I am using RFC standard HTTP compression.

I need to optimise for CPU consumption. I wonder if there is any threshold, something like: *if a string is more than 100 chars, then it is worth doing compression*.

**Should I always apply compression for HTTP payload or only when its worth doing?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the CPU overhead caused by compression on very small files is close to zero. So, I don't think it's worth doing a test on the file size.

The most worrying aspect in your description is actually that you apparently have many small requests over HTTPS. If it's not already the case, I would recommend to enable SSL session caching in order to avoid too many SSL handshakes, which are likely to consume more CPU than compressing 100 bytes or so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use CPU profiler, the utilisation comes up top for compression, hence I am trying to reduce its impact. Re SSL session cache - good call, I've checked it was already turned on. In fact, it's on by default for CURL (which I use).

Comment: Am I right to assume that the compression is performed outside CURL? (I don't think CURL has native support for POST data compression.) Could you try to reduce the size of the DEFLATE sliding window to reduce the load on large files? (provided that it's OK to have slightly reduced compression ratios) Also, are the files cached once compressed? (If that makes any sense at all in your project.)

Comment: Compression is done outside of CURL, it doesn't support content compression for HTTP POSTs. I am sending an equivalent of real-time logs, so the size of a sliding windows is already about a second. Under high load (10k messages/sec) I get a lot of benefit by compressing it. I could play about with the compression ratio - never thought of that. Thanks for your help.